# Different groups for same user

Tags: active-directory, pam

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with a remote active directory server. To login on my Ubuntu machine, I use the username and password from active directory.

I recently had to run `pam-auth-update` because it was no longer possible to log in with my AD credentials. However after running this, my groups seem to be mixed up.

The following information should help clarifying my problem:

```
myusername@machine:~$ whoami          
myusername
myusername@machine:~$ id
uid=10004608(myusername) gid=10000513(domänen-benutzer) Gruppen=10000513(domänen-benutzer)
 myusername@machine:~$ id myusername
uid=10004608(myusername) gid=10000513(domänen-benutzer) Gruppen=10000513(domänen-benutzer),999(docker),132(wireshark),10004608(myusername),[... a lot more AD groups]
myusername@machine:~$ su - myusername
Password: 
myusername@machine:~$ id
uid=10004608(myusername) gid=10000513(domänen-benutzer) Gruppen=10000513(domänen-benutzer),132(wireshark),999(docker),10004608(myusername),[... a lot more AD groups]
myusername@machine:~$ whoami
myusername
myusername@machine:~$
```

Running `su - myusername` gives me all my usual groups like docker, but my login shell only gives me only a subset of my usual groups.

I guess I have to change some config file in /etc/pam.d but I have no clue what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I am not the only one with this problem, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458523) helped me solve the problem.

To be precise, I had to comment out the following two lines from `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

```
auth optional pam_kwallet.so
auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```